# App under "Export Compliance Review" - should I re-submit?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to publish an iOS app that uses encryption on the AppStore. I've uploaded the ERN to iTunes Connect, and then got an e-mail from Apple stating:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for submitting your App to the AppStore.  The App is currently under “Export Compliance Review” due to missing information or additional clarification is needed.
>
> Missing Information:
>
> “App Description” is blank.  Please provide the function of the app.
>
> “Availability” is blank.  Please provide the countries where the app will be distributed.
>
> Regards,
>
>  Apple Export Compliance

I've updated those fields something like a week ago, but I'm not sure if I have to take any other step - re-submitting something, or whatever -, or if I just have to wait until Apple decides to re-review my app.

Any info on this?

Answer (score 2):

Once you update/provide the information required by the reviewer, you need to reply to the reviewer's message in the resolution centre.

The reviewer will be intimated after your reply and it is when the review of your App will be resumed.